# Exposure of IR swap with Least Square Monte Carlo (Longstaff)

Tags: exposure

Hey how to calculate Expected positive exposure in the case of interest rate swap? Assume that I simulate M
interest rate paths for time grid 0=t0≤t1≤...≤tN=T.
What is the procedure now to calculate value of a swap for each trajectory and each time step using Longstaff-Schwarz LSM? I know that in the case of american option we can go backward but I dont understand how to do it in the case of IR swap. Its easy to calculate cash flows at each time t1,...,tN
but what next?